# How to run .exe files in NSIS successively?

Tags: nsis

With NSIS I'm creating an installer for a selfmade software suite. This installer needs to run three `.exe` files.

With

```
Exec "Execute1.exe"
Exec "Execute2.exe"
Exec "Execute3.exe"
```

I run all those files. The problem is all files are running parallel. I want to run the files successively - first `Execute1.exe`, then `Execute2.exe` and `Execute3.exe` at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ExecWait`](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Reference/ExecWait) instead:

> ```
> ExecWait command [user_var(exit code)]
> ```
>
> Execute the specified program and wait for the executed process to quit.

```
ExecWait "Execute1.exe"
ExecWait "Execute2.exe"
ExecWait "Execute3.exe"
```

Answer (score 1):

`ExecWait` is what you are looking for. I'd link to documentation, but online links seem to be broken.

```
File "${MSVSREDIST}\${MSVSREDISTFILE2008}"
ExecWait '"${ExtractPath}\${MSVSREDISTFILE2008}" /q'

File "${MSVSREDIST}\${MSVSREDISTFILE2010}"
ExecWait '"${ExtractPath}\${MSVSREDISTFILE2010}" /passive /norestart'

File "${DOTNET}\${DOTNETFILE}"
ExecWait '"${ExtractPath}\${DOTNETFILE}" /passive /norestart'
```